# css code to remove the unnecessary white space

Tags: html, css

When horizontal scrolling is kept by default from right hand side to left hand side, i noticed a white space on the left hand side which is to be removed. Issue is could not able to remove the white space shown on the left hand side when scrolling from right to left side. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Demo link : 
 http://jsfiddle.net/3xa69njt/

```js
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Adult', 'Child','Infant', 'Senior'],
          ['2004',  11,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  12,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  13,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  14,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  15,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  11,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  12,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  13,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  14,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  15,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  11,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  12,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  13,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  14,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  15,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  11,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  12,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  13,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  14,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  15,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  11,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  12,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2004',  13,      14, 2, 9],
          ['2005',  14,      14, 2, 9]
        
          
        ]);

        var options = {            
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
          width: data.getNumberOfRows() * 130,
          bar: {groupWidth: 90},
          chartArea: {left:60, width:'94%'} 
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```css
#chart_div {
 overflow-x: auto; 
 overflow-y: hidden;     
  direction:rtl;
height:500px;
        
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Tried using `margin-left : 0px;left:0px;` but of no luck.

--Edited--
As mentioned i want the scrollbar to be scrolled from right to left direction, that is the reason for using `direction:rtl`.

Comment: Do you really need `direction: rtl`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block;` It will remove the space

like below

```
#chart_div {
overflow-x: auto; 
overflow-y: hidden;     
direction:rtl;
height:500px;
display:inline-block;       
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xa69njt/1/)

Comment: Either I don't understand the question or your solution won't work? Maybe you could add `overflow: hidden`, then it works like expected.

Comment: see the fiddle of Op's  when the chart loads the  horizontal scroll moves to right because of unwanted space at left side . . so I suggested an answer to remove it  see the both fiddles  you will get it i hope so  @PatrickMlr

Comment: just try your code with browser it will work. don't know why it is not with js fiddel.. may be some issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `direction:rtl;` from your CSS code and it will work fine.

here is working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/kjwhnx1q/3/

**CSS code:**

```
#chart_div {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure, why do you need direction here. It works fine when removing it.

Here is the [fiddle](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) working fine.

Check on this [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) to know more about direction property.

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3xa69njt/2/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#chart_div {
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 direction: rtl;
 height: 500px;
 display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -20px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: As mentioned i want the scrollbar to be scrolled from right to left direction, that is the reason for using `direction:rtl`.
None of the answers suggested above are working, still i can see the white space on left hand side when moved the scrollbar from right to left side.